# Image menu showing categories in page

Tags: categories, images

I'm trying to display different images in a page that links to categories.

Currently i have a page that shows the categories and the pages for the categories but it needs a slight change.

I need to display the category name with an image for that category and a background for it. I've attached an image to explain what i mean properly.

I think the part i'm having trouble with is the background image and the image for the category. I can get it to display the category name it's just the background image and the image for the category.

What's the best way to do this in wordpress?

Here's a link to the design. http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/3587/imagecategorymenu.jpg

In this design Products is the page title and the four sections are different categories. Clicking on Printers for example will take you to another page show the same thing but with sub categories of printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at a plugin like [images for categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-images-ii/) and seeing if you can extend it to allow 2 images per category.

Comment: I didn't need to extend it to use two images. I tried using this plugin but found another that i find much easier to use. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-page-icons/